# LambdaExpressions

Tags: expression

I need to write a LambdaExpression which is given below:

```
(a) => a.o.MovieType
```

where the definition of a is:

```
public class A<T, U> : EntityObject
    where T : EntityObject
    where U : EntityObject
{
    public T o { get; private set; }
    public U p { get; private set; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, U, A<T, U>>> TempProjectedExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return (o, p) => new A<T, U>
            {
                o = o,
                p = p
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the following lambdaExpression to achieve my goal i.e. (a) => a.o.MovieType

```
me = Expression.Property(pe1, _ResultantType.GetProperty("o").PropertyType.GetProperty(aPropertyName[0]));
```

The error i got is:
Tha parameter MovieType is not bound in the specified Linq to Entities Expression.

I modified it, after i realized that the problem appears too complicated than it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I realized that the error is popping up for not building the Expression tree properly.
(a) => a.o.MovieType should be understood like two Expressions within one lambda expression.

Hence, the solution should be programmatically something like this:

```
(a) => (a.o) => a.o.MovieType

Expression<Func<A,B>> Exp1 = sample => sample.o;
```

i.e.

```
Expression<Func<Expression<Func<A,B>>,int>> Exp = sample => Exp1.Invoke(p.MovieType,p);
```